# Ffmpeg on Windows: use mp3 as audio codec to create mp4 files

Tags: flash, encoding, mp3, ffmpeg, mp4

I'm using ffmpeg on Windows to create mp4 files for web distribution. As libfaac isn't available, I use libmp3lame to encode the audio tracks. The mp4 are played back with a falsh player (JWPlayer)

I was wondering if there were any shortcomings to use mp3 instead of aac on certain devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If JWPlayer can handle it, it's fine. MP3 is a more open and portable format to begin with.